# Matlab indexing within eval

Tags: matlab, indexing, eval

I would like to change values within an dataset using eval. It shlould be in a way thet every second value is changed to the one before.

Short example:

```
A = magic(6)
ds = mat2dataset(A) % original dataset

ds.A1(2:2:end) = ds.A1(1:2:end) % dataset after change
```

That's the way I would like to do it. Now I need to use the variables letter and number which are assigned previous in the function.

```
letter = 'A'
number = '1'

eval([strcat('ds.', letter, number)]) % now gives me all values.
```

This is exactly the point where I would like to index the (1:2:end) to get just the indexed values.

Does one of you have a good idea how to index within the eval function? I would also prefer other ways of doing it if you have on.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Don't use `eval` to achieve dynamic fieldnames:

```
h=ds.([letter, number])
```

2) Double indexing is not possible, you need two lines to achieve it.

```
h(1:2:end)
```